# How to know which Sata Channel my dev/sd* associated with

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid

Just in case for me (and others) when a software raid 5 degraded, how do I know which Sata Channel my dev/sda, /dev/sdb, etc. associated with, so that we can replace them properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than trying to identify the failed disk by the SATA channel it's connected to, you can identify it by its serial number. I have found that most hard disks these days have their serial numbers stamped/printed on the front edge, so all you need to do is determine the serial number of the failed drive.

I assume you have already discovered the logical name of the failed drive via `cat /proc/mdstat`. For the sake of example, let's assume that failed drive is `/dev/sdb`.

Next, if you haven't got it already, install the `lshw` package, and then run this command (I'm not sure if you need to `sudo` it; it's harmless to try it with/without `sudo`):

```
lshw -class disk
```

You should get output that looks something like the following:

```
  *-disk:0
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST32000542AS
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: CC34
       serial: 1AB23C45
       size: 1863GiB (2TB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=12345678
  *-disk:1
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST32000542AS
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: CC34
       serial: 6DE78FG9
       size: 1863GiB (2TB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=90abcdef
```

From this, you should be able to identify the problem drive from its `logical name` (e.g. `/dev/sdb`), and thus obtain its serial number (e.g. `6DE78FG9`). With the serial number in hand, you can be confident you're pulling the correct drive.

(If your failed drive doesn't show up in the `lshw` output at all, then it's **really** dead. You can probably still use `lshw` to find the dead drive, but this time by process of elimination.)

Answer (score 0):

This file will give you RAID informations like which drives are assigned to each RAID

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```