# What happen when you replace a broken harddrive with a bigger one into RAID5

Tags: software-raid, mdadm, raid5

Given I have a raid 5 of `/dev/sda`, `dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, now with the same size (said 250G)
But later, `/dev/sda` failed, so I replaced it with `/dev/sdd` of 500G. What happens?

If Later I replace `/dev/sdb` with `/dev/sde` of 500G and `/dev/sdc` with `/dev/sdf` of 500G then what happen?

Will my array grow it capability?

Comment: By 'software-raid' do you mean 'mdadm'? If so please re-tag and you'll get more answers.

Answer (score 3):

[Based on [another recent question of yours](https://serverfault.com/q/252429/57024), I assume you're using Linux `mdadm` for software RAID. If this is not the case, feel free to ignore this.]

The size of your RAID5 array will not grow automatically after you have replaced all the 250G drives in the array (one at a time, of course!) with 500G drives. You will need to tell `mdadm` to grow the array, using the `--grow` operation. Something like the following should grow the array to fill the new larger drives:

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max
```

Answer (score 2):

1. When you are using mismatched drives, the new (larger) drives will have un-utilised space on them. You are usually free to use this space for other partitions or arrays.
2. When you have upgraded all your drives to drives of the same size, what you can do with it depends on a lot of factors, like the method you've used for RAID etc. With any decent RAID controller, you can expand your array to fill the full size of all the disks. The same might also be true depending on your soft-raid options. Windows, for example, can't expand a RAID array, but I assume from your disk descriptions you're using *nix, which I'm not so familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have personal experience with RAID5, but the Linux RAID Wiki has a detailed instruction guide:

https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Growing#Expanding_existing_partitions